# I have restricted my API key using package name and signed SHA1 key, but I'm still receiving warning on Google Play store

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play-console

[I have added image for refrence]

Security alert

> Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys. Please see this Google Help Center article for details.
>   Vulnerable locations:...

What could be the reason behind it?
How can I remove this warning?

Comment: using google map ?

Answer (score 0):

The above case is especially when you are using an API key that publishes on any public platform like GitHub public repository. or any public blog. google detect that key is being used publically so it has given you an error for GCP API keys.

What you have to do go to your GCP console and generate new key make sure you are not exposing anything on public repo or blogs. and put it into your APK.